# Copula function and relatioships between stocks

Tags: python, distribution

How to use copulas to establish a relationship between returns of 4 stocks?

I have stocks returns data:

```
[-1.0, -1.7, -1.65, ...] # 1 stock
[-1.2, -0.1, 1.2, ...] # 2 stock
...
[-2.0, -2.5, 4.12, ...] # 4 stock
```

And I have

```
### 3 Basic Copula Functions ###
def lowerBound(X, Y):
    Z = np.maximum(X + Y - 1, 0)
    return Z

def productCopula(X, Y):
    Z = X * Y
    return Z

def upperBound(X, Y):
    Z = np.minimum(X, Y)
    return Z
```

How can I determine the relationship between returns using this or ANY other library?

Comment: what kind of relationship you want please be more specific. Is it possible to show expected result you want.

Comment: I do not have specific requirements that need to be obtained as a result. It will be great if I get something intuitive. For example, a matrix with coupling coefficients or something like that. I just want to understand how can I determine the relationship between returns using copulas

Comment: This is a new field for me and it is still difficult for me to understand it, without any real examples.